# jquery waypoint plugin does not work properly

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-waypoints

In my code does not work $(this) in jquery waypoint function,without $(this) everything works

```
<script>
    $('.team-member').waypoint(function (){
        $(this).addClass('bgr');
    }, {
        offset: '70%'
    });
</script>
```

сss

```
.bgr {
  background: red;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flexible way to work Waypont plugin is to do so

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('waypoint'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    console.log('Scrolled to waypoint!')
  }
})
```

Also you can try this one

```
$('.team-member').waypoint(function (){
  var thisE = $(this)[0]['element'];
  $(thisE).addClass('bgr');
  }, {
    offset: '70%'
});
```

In your case `$(this)` refers to waypoint object not to specific dom element thats why your code brakes.Console log `$(this)` and you will see.

```
$('.team-member').waypoint(function (){
    console.log( $(this) )
}, {
    offset: '70%'
});
```

Comment: thank you.It works. Could you explain, why I have this problem?